# Issue with httpclient.getstringasync

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I want to develop a Dragon Timer Windows Store App for GuildWars 2.
Whatever, I save a timestamp in a sql database. To get this timestamp in the app, I made a php script that writes the content of the database to a page. Now I'm trying to receive that string via the HttpClient.GetStringAsync() Method. Here's the code snipped:

```
async Task<Dictionary<String, DateTime>> GetKillTimes()
    {
        Dictionary<String, DateTime> killTimes = new Dictionary<String,DateTime>();

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> getStringTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.wp10454523.server-he.de/truhentimer/getTimes.php");

        String rawKillTimes = await getStringTask;

        //Parse to Dictionary...

        return killTimes;
    }
```

I tried some different Methods I got from google (WebRequest ...), but every one got stuck at the Get-Part. Am I maybe misinterpreting the function? Shouldn't I get the content of the page, which is a simple String?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `await` keyword as web request & response in WinRT are asynchronous so you have to use `await` keyword. `await` before `httpClient.GetStringAsync(...)`

```
Task<string> getStringTask = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.wp10454523.server-he.de/truhentimer/getTimes.php");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe you missed it, but the `await` stands in front of  `getStringTask` in the next line. Thats's how i found it on a Microsoft page. Howsoever, if I try yours, I have to change `Task<string>` to `String` (cause of conversion) and it gets stuck anyway.

Comment: oh my bad, I tried your code I am getting the result `Tequatl,2013-06-01 18:30:19,Golem,2013-06-01 18:30:17,Dschungelwurm,2013-06-01 17:30:17,Feuerelementar,2013-06-01 18:15:17,Klaue Jormags,2013-06-01 18:38:17,Der Zerschmetterer,2013-06-01 18:45:17,` in `rawKillTimes` variable.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Seems like I messed something up with the calling of the method.

Comment: Hmmm, let me know when you get the response. Please also check if your Internet is working or not. Do you have selected `Internet(Client)` in `capability` tab in `Package.appxmanifest` file ?